# Meta Viewport Tag options does not work on iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iframe

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Fox News</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="https://s2.googleusercontent.com/s2/favicons?domain_url=http://foxnews.com" type="image/gif" sizes="16x16">
  <style>
    body {
      margin: auto;
    }
    
    .iframe-container {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    .iframe-container iframe,
    .iframe-container object,
    .iframe-container embed {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      margin: 0px;
      border: 0;
    }
    
    .social-magnet {
      position: fixed;
      left: 10px;
      font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    }
    
    .clx_iframe {
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      bottom: 30px;
      left: 5%;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100px;
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    
    .socialbar {
      width: 87px;
      height: 87px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      border: none;
      pointer-events: fill;
      box-shadow: none;
      z-index: 101;
      position: absolute;
      top: 35%;
      left: 147px;
      border-radius: 50% !important;
    }
    
    .profilePhoto {
      width: 87px;
      height: 87px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border: 3px dashed lightgray;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
      object-fit: contain;
    }
    
    .messageContainer {
      width: 390px;
      height: auto;
      line-height: 18px;
      padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: 2px solid white;
      border-radius: 5px;
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
      color: black;
      background-color: white;
      text-shadow: none;
      pointer-events: fill;
      box-shadow: none;
      opacity: 1;
      z-index: 100;
    }
    
    .circle-div {
      background: #4C4E60;
      height: 20px;
      border-radius: 50% !important;
      width: 20px;
      float: right;
      position: relative;
      top: -20px;
      right: -25px;
      color: white;
    }
    
    #minimizeToggle {
      color: white;
      opacity: 0.75;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-weight: bolder;
      font-size: 13px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    #logosocial {
      float: right;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding-right: 2.5px;
      padding-left: 2.5px;
    }
    
    .logoImage {
      width: 46px;
      height: 20px;
      margin-top: -5px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 100%;
      opacity: 0.6;
      position: relative;
      right: -25px;
    }
    
    #profileName {
      width: 77%;
      line-height: 20px;
      font-size: 15px;
      padding-bottom: 3px;
      text-align: left;
      color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
      display: block;
      opacity: 0.6;
      overflow: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    #message {
      height: 36px;
      margin-top: 4px;
      display: table;
      text-align: left;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: auto;
      letter-spacing: 0.5px;
      color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
    }
    
    #messageText {
      height: auto;
      width: 100%;
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
      word-wrap: break-word;
      word-break: break-all;
    }
    
    #formButton {
      float: right;
      margin-left: 15px;
      cursor: pointer;
      color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      background-color: #4C4E60;
      width: 90%;
    }
    
    .triangle {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      background: white;
      box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    }
    
    .triangle::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      margin-left: -0.5em;
      bottom: -2em;
      left: 45%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 1em solid black;
      border-color: transparent transparent white white;
      transform-origin: 0 0;
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
      box-shadow: -3px 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    }
    
    .buttonCTA {
      height: 36px;
      width: auto;
      display: table-cell;
      padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
      margin: 0 0 0 15px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 3px solid #4C4E60;
      line-height: 35px;
      font-weight: 400 !important;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-align: center;
    }
    /* Media Queiries */
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 359px) and (min-width: 320px) {
      .messageContainer {
        width: 300px;
      }
      .socialbar {
        left: 107px;
      }
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 374px) and (min-width: 360px) {
      .messageContainer {
        width: 340px;
      }
      .socialbar {
        left: 125px;
      }
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 413px) and (min-width: 375px) {
      .messageContainer {
        width: 355px;
      }
      .socialbar {
        left: 133px;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="iframeWrapper" class="iframe-container">
    <iframe id="website_frame" class="iframe" src="https://foxnews.com" sandbox='allow-forms allow-scripts allow-same-origin' allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <div class="social-magnet">
      <div class="messageContainer triangle">
        <div class="circle-div"><a id="minimizeToggle" href="http://foxnews.com">x</a></div>
        <a id="logosocial" href="https://clickx.io?utm_source=http://www.clickx.io&utm_campaign=contact&utm_medium=offerwidget" target="_blank">
          <div class="logoImage"></div>
          <a id="profileName" href="http://foxnews.com" target="_blank">Kannan Devan</a>
        </a>
        <span id="message">
          <span id="messageText" class="text-left">
            Good evening. Spent the Evening with a cup of TEA
          </span>
        </span>
        <a class="buttonCTA" id="formButton" href="http://foxnews.com" target="_blank">
          Hello Guys
        </a>
      </div>
      <span class="socialbar">
        <a id="imageLink" href="http://foxnews.com" target="_blank">
          <img id="image_src" class="profilePhoto" src='https://ffb2efd5105ff0aedbc9-9cdacdeebf0faa19b665bf427f0c8092.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/assets/new-creator/plus-icon4.png' alt="Brand Logo">
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('social-magnet')[0];
    var image_wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('socialbar')[0];
    var height = document.getElementsByClassName('messageContainer')[0].offsetHeight;
    wrapper.style.bottom = (height + 132).toString() + 'px';
    image_wrapper.style.marginTop = (height + 40).toString() + 'px';
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried to load a website in a plain HTML page using iFrame.

When opening in desktops, the desktop version of the site is opened.
Also when opening in Android phones, the mobile version is loaded, which is the expected behavior.

But the problem is that, when opening in iPhones, the desktop version of the website is loaded.

Comment: What is the exact tag you're using?

Comment: @the4kman I'm using `<iframe>` tag itself

Comment: I mean, what are the `meta` `viewport` tags?

Comment: @the4kman Wait i will update the code snippet

Comment: @the4kman Can you look into it now ?

Comment: You may want to inject the tag into the iframe's content as well.

Comment: @the4kman Did not get you. Can you make it more clear ?

Comment: @the4kman I tried injecting, still, it is not working dude :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the iFrame property `scrolling='no'` made it look like the mobile version of the website to be loaded correctly on iOS.

```
  var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
  ifrm.setAttribute("src", "<%= @social_snip.url %>");
  ifrm.id = 'ContentFrame';
  ifrm.scrolling = 'yes';
  if (check) {
    document.getElementById('iframeWrapper').className += ' mobile-theme';
  }
  var IOS = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream;
  if(IOS) {
    ifrm.scrolling = 'no';
  }
```

The above code checks whether the OS is an iOS, if yes it will set the `scrolling` property of iFrame with a  `no`  value.